# VueJS: How can I get the parameter of the class that was clicked on?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, vue.js

I'm making a photo gallery using Vue. I created a JS class called Photo

```
class Photo {
  constructor(img, name) {
    this.img = img;
    this.name = name;
  }
}
```

I'm then passing that class into a photoGallery array

```
data: {
    photoGallery: [
        new Photo(
            'img/pic-1.jpg',
            'Picture One'
        ),
        new Photo(
            'img/pic-2.jpg',
            'Picture Two'
        )
    ]
}
```

And outputting all the Photos in the array into a list

```
<ul class="gallery" id="gallery">
        <li v-for="photo in photoGallery" class="photo" 
        :style="{'backgroundImage': 'url(' + photo.img + ')'}"></li>
</ul>
```

I also have an image tag above the outputted photos

```
<div class="selected-photo" id="selected-photo">
     <img src="#">
</div>
```

What I want is to create a method that takes the `img` parameter of the `Photo` you selected, and pushes it into the `img` tag above the list of images.

But I'm unsure how I'd go about doing that. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have one more data variable: say `selectedIdx`, which will have the index of selected image:

```
data: {
    photoGallery: [
        new Photo(
            'img/pic-1.jpg',
            'Picture One'
        ),
        new Photo(
            'img/pic-2.jpg',
            'Picture Two'
        )
    ],
    selectedIdx: null
}
```

And in the `v-for` you can set this variable with [v-on:click](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-on)  or `@click` in short  like following:

```
<ul class="gallery" id="gallery">
        <li v-for="(photo, idx) in photoGallery" class="photo"  @click="selectedIdx = idx"
        :style="{'backgroundImage': 'url(' + photo.img + ')'}"></li>
</ul>
```

Now with this, you can use it in `img` tag with help of [v-bind](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind) or with `:` in short:

```
<div class="selected-photo" id="selected-photo">
     <img :src="photoGallery[selectedIdx].img" >  //I am not sure which method will give you image path
</div>
```

Comment: Changed selectedIdx to 0 instead of null so it'll show the first picture when you load in. It worked perfectly! Thank you so much!